# Зачем нужны функции возвращаюшие коллекции в SQL контексте?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Недавно узнал, что можно в SQL запросе вернуть коллекцию. Например вот так:

```
select 
  cast (multiset
    (select поле from таблица)
  as тип коллекции) 
from dual
```

Зачем это нужно в SQL, если работать с коллекциями можно только в PL/SQL коде?

Comment: Наверное, всё-таки имеются в виду команды SQL внутри PL/SQL кода? Самый очевидный пример - массовое связывание. Тогда в одной команде используется и оператор PL/SQL, например FORALL и обращение в списке столбцов выборки к элементам коллекции.

Comment: эти функции можно вызывать просто в sql движке

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Функция  `cast` с ключевым словом `multiset` конвертирует набор реляционных данных в SQL коллекцию. Основное назначение, манипуляция данных в таблицах с колонками объявлеными как коллекции.

Другое применение - маппинг классической схемы с реляционной моделью данных с объектно-реляционной посредством объектных представлений.

Подготовим данные:

```
create or replace type myItemType as object (id number, name varchar(32));
/
create type myItemArrayType as table of myItemType;
/
create table myItems (items myItemArrayType) nested table items store as items_table;
/
```

Вставка коллекции с одним элементом:

```
insert into myItems values (myItemArrayType (myItemType (0, 'item 0')));

1 row inserted.
```

Вставка коллекции из объектного представления реляционных таблиц. Вместо `dual` здесь одна или соединение нескольких таблиц:

```
insert into myItems select cast (multiset (
    select level, 'item ' || level from dual connect by level <= 5  
) as myItemArrayType) from dual;

1 row inserted.
```

Запрос выведет `item 0` из первой строчки, коллекцию `item 1 - item 5` из второй:

```
select items.*, dbms_rowid.rowid_row_number (t.rowid) rnum
from myItems t cross join table (items) items;

 ID NAME      RNUM
--- -------- -----
  0 item 0       0
  1 item 1       1
  2 item 2       1
  3 item 3       1
  4 item 4       1
  5 item 5       1
```

Comment: select cast (multiset(select поле from таблица)as тип коллекции) from dual. Этот код можно вызвать просто из sql.

Comment: Конечно можно, А где метод для работы с коллекциями в этом select?

Comment: возможно не правильно сформулировал, суть зачем коллекция в sql?

Comment: Или измените вопрос, или задайте новый. Вопрос "зачем коллекция в sql" - поставлен очень обобщённо. Коллекции испльзуются начиная с 8-й версии. Mетка plsql только с толку сбивает.

Comment: пример который я написал как можно использовать на практике? Зачем коллекций в oracle понятно, зачем они нужны в выборке sql/

Comment: Могу только вечером посмотреть.